# How to write XPATH which have text and multiple tags in div

Tags: xpath

I have below sample HTML:

```
<div class="content">
  <h3>Text</h3>
  "Temp Text"
</div>
```

How to write XPath to locate "Temp Text"?

Something like `//div[text()='Temp Text']`

Comment: `//div/text()[contains(., 'Temp Text')]` may be what you want?

Comment: I guess 'Temp Text' may be unknown beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the div with "Temp Text", you will need to do:

```
//div[text()[contains(., "Temp Text")]]
```

`//div[text()='Temp Text']` does not work because the div actually has 2 text nodes - one before the h3 and one after.

Comment: It would help if you elaborate on "doesn't work" - do you mean it returns nothing, returns the wrong thing, etc.?

Comment: It returns the whole div and i need only "Temp Text"

Comment: Got it should be //div[@ class='content']/text()[2]